# Breakpoint icon types in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, breakpoints

While using Visual Studio Code, I’ve met at least three types of breakpoint icons:
[image: screenshot]

How do these types differ? Is there any explanation available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover your mouse cursor over a breakpoint in the editor, you’ll get a description of the breakpoint type.

Example:

[image: screenshot of Unverified Breakpoint]